# How to access 'conn' in the Controller module outside an action

Tags: phoenix-framework

I want to be able to define a variable that needs to access to `conn` in my controller module but outside any action so that I can use it in any action:

```
defmodule Skeleton.Web.PageController do
  use Skeleton.Web, :controller
  locale = conn |> get_session(:locale)

  def news(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, "news.html", locale: locale)"
  end
end
```

How to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The code in the module is evaluated once at compilation. `conn` is a unique value that's created for each request and passed to the action.

You can override the `action/2` function to extract and pass the locale to each action:

```
def action(conn, _) do
  args = [conn, conn.params, get_session(conn, :locale)]
  apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn), args)
end
```

<sup>[Source](https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/05/02/phoenix-tips-and-tricks)</sup>

Now each action in the controller will get 3 arguments, `conn`, `params`, and `locale`:

```
def news(conn, _params, locale) do
  render(conn, "news.html", locale: locale)"
end
```

---

You can also create a helper function but the code would not be much shorter in this case as you'll have to explicitly pass `conn` to it:

```
def news(conn, _params) do
  render(conn, "news.html", locale: locale(conn))"
end

def locale(conn), do: get_session(conn, :locale)
```